# How to make that an email seen in PHP (Yii1) with IMAP not change to "seen" automatically every time I see it?

Tags: php, yii, imap

Every time I run my function and this load my index, the table with my emails appears with the new emails, but every time I see the email, in gmail that email changes to "read" or "seen" and then it doesn't appear.

My function:

public function actionLeerCorreo(){

```
        set_time_limit(4000); 

        // Connect to gmail
        $imapPath = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
        $username = 'mesa.ayuda@gmail.com';
        $password = 'mesaayuda';

        // try to connect 
        $inbox = imap_open($imapPath,$username,$password) or die('No se puede conectar a Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

        $emails = imap_search($inbox,'UNSEEN');

        echo '<table class="table table-dark">';
        echo '<thead>';
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<th scope="col">Subject</th>';
        echo '<th scope="col">Email</th>';
        //echo '<th scope="col">From adress</th>';
        echo '<th scope="col">Message</th>';
        echo '<th scope="col">Date</th>';
        echo '<th scope="col"> </th>';
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '</thead>';
        $mensaje = '';

        if($emails){
        rsort($emails); 
        foreach($emails as $mail) {
            //$status = imap_setflag_full($inbox, $mail, '\\SEEN', 0);
            //$status = $mail->SetMailFlag($inbox, $mail, '\\SEEN', 0);
            imap_clearflag_full($inbox, $mail, "\\Unseen", 0); 
            $headerInfo = imap_headerinfo($inbox,$mail);
            //$status = imap_setflag_full($inbox, $mail, "\\Unseen", ST_UID);
            $emailStructure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox,$mail);
            //$mensaje .= imap_body($inbox, $mail, FT_PEEK); 
            $mensaje = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$mail,2);

            $fecha = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($headerInfo->date));
            $asunto = $headerInfo->subject;
            $correo = $headerInfo->fromaddress;

            echo '<tr>';
                  echo '<td>'.$subject.'</td>';
                  echo '<td>'.$fromadress.'</td>';
                  echo '<td>'.$message.'</td>';
                  echo '<td>'.$date.'</td>';

            }
        }
          echo '</table>';

        // colse the connection
        imap_expunge($inbox);
        imap_close($inbox);

        $this->renderPartial('email');
```

}

Please help me :(

Comment: Use PEEK.  That’s what it’s for.

Comment: @Matiburon please remove you credentials from the code